# xcode 4.3 - storyboard - iAd keeps moving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iad

I have added iAd to my iphone app to be at the top of my app. originally I place it at x=0 and y=-50 so that it comes from off the screen. I use the following code for it in my .m :

```
    - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)abanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)abanner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
```

When my app launch iAd get displayed at the top without any problem. but when I open another app and come back to it (without killing it so my app is running in the background) the banner moves another 50 pixel down[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `50.0px` to `banner.frame.origin.y` in both cases.

Anyway: even if you'd be substracting `50.px` in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` it 
could happen that `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` would get called multiple times in a
row and your code could move the banner higher and higher up (-50.0,-100.0,-150.0...).

So it's better to hardcode the hidden & visible positions instead of calculating it.

Try this:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)abanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,-50.0,banner.frame.size.width,banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)abanner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,banner.frame.size.width,banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding it leaves a white blank bar when there is no ad. That is why I initially have it off the screen then I move it on when there is an ad to be displayed.

Comment: I mean hardcode it's off and it's on position - not to put it on fixed place. Did you try the suggested code?